# Does the "%defattr" directive affect the "%post" section also in rpm spec file?

Tags: package, redhat, rpm, rpmbuild, rpm-spec

I have a .spec file with code somewhat like this:

```
%files
%defattr(-,xyz, xyz)
%verify(md5 size mtime mode) %attr(755, xyz, xyz) /usr/bin/app1
%verify(md5 size mtime mode) %attr(755, xyz, xyz) /usr/bin/app2

%post
mkdir -p /apps/1/logs
mkdir -p /apps/2/logs
mkdir -p /apps/3/logs
mkdir -p /apps/4/logs
mkdir -p /apps/5/logs
ln -sf /usr/bin/app1 /usr/bin/app3
touch /home/xyz/abc.log
```

will the %defattr also affect the default attributes of files and directories getting created in the post section??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No. You'll need to explicitly `chown/chmod` anything you do in `%post`. It's preferred to *not* have them in `%post` because things can break that way (like `rpm -V`). Why *wouldn't* you want that to be done in `%build`?